# Need help. No voodoo demons spawning!

Tags: terraria-mobile

I can’t find any voodoo demons  in the underworld. I’ve spent 3 hours trying to get one voodoo doll to do the wall of flesh. I used battle potions and water candles to try to get one but can’t.

Answer (score -2):

This has happened to me too! All I did was kill the guide a different way like slimes, keeping one voodoo doll and blood moons. This worked for me, but I needed to wait around 5 minutes, then go to the underworld.